# how to make a halfling manticore rider?

Tags: age-of-wonders-3

I've found the Halfling Manticore Rider in the Tome of Wonders.
It's the only t4 halfling unit I could find.
However I cannot find what must be done to actually make the unit.
What chain of buildings grants access?

I see the unit becomes available when you build the Great Beast Lair.
But I don't have that building available in my other game.
Is it that this building/unit can only be build by a halfling warlord?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's worth a mention that in Age of Wonders 3, unlike previous installments, higher Tier units are provided by class instead of race.

For the Warlord, this is the Manticore Rider. There's one for every race, including the Halflings.

All class unit require the class building in that city to be the appropriate Tier. For the Manticore Rider, that's the Great Beast Lair, which requires the Warlord's Command and Gladiator Pit to already be built.

However, class units also need to be researched - the Produce Manticore Rider empire upgrade. This is the last technology in the line of Warlord Class Units. For reference, this is the research order of [Warlord class units](https://age-of-wonders-3.fandom.com/wiki/Warlord):

- Raise Militia
- Produce Beserker
- Produce Monster Hunter
- Produce Mounted Archer
- Produce Phalanx
- Produce Warbreed
- Produce Manticore Rider

Class unit research is configured to always be available.

(Note: Currently the wiki layout seems to be heavily damaged as side effect of Fandom global overhauls. Sorry about that.)

(Disclaimer: I personally contributed heavily to the above wiki.)